# Get MySQL Server Version with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I'm building out an app in Laravel 5 and I need to ensure that one of my tables will be able to perform FULLTEXT searches.

I'd like to detect the MySQL version number(ensuring it's at least 5.6.10 or above) so that I can switch the engine to MyISAM in my migration file for a given table, if that condition fails.

I can't seem to find any docs on how to access the MySQL server info using PDO, which is what Laravel uses out of the box.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just run `select version();` query, which will give you all-correct result no matter which API you are using?

```
echo $pdo->query('select version()')->fetchColumn();
```

### is throwing me not a single error

Comment: Ah sorry, I see, I had to grab my PDO instance from Laravel. Works great thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `PDO::getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION)`
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.getattribute.php

Comment: `use PDO` throws this: `The use statement with non-compound name 'PDO' has no effect` and `use \PDO` throws this: `Non-static method PDO::getAttribute() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context` WTF?

Comment: @VinceKronlein This is a non-static method, which must be called on an instance of `PDO`, i.e. `$pdo->getAttribute(...)`.

Answer (score 4):

A little improved version of Vince Kronlein's answer

```
function version($min){
    $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
    $version = $pdo->query('select version()')->fetchColumn();

    preg_match("/^[0-9\.]+/", $version, $match);

    $version = $match[0];

    return (version_compare($version, $min) >= 0);
}
```

Usage:

```
if(version('5.7.0')){
    //do someting
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this break when a version like 5.10.10 is reached? your substring would not work anymore?

Comment: @TomSomerville Correct, thanks for noting this. I updated my answer with a quick regex match, this should now work with longer versions too.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a little method in my migration file:

```
protected static function version() 
{
    $pdo     = DB::connection()->getPdo();
    $version = $pdo->query('select version()')->fetchColumn();

    (float)$version = mb_substr($version, 0, 6);

    if ($version < '5.6.10') {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Works a charm. Thanks for the comments.