# php pdo get database version(MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is there any ways I can get MySQL version using PDO ?

I want to set charset for my connection but as utf8mb4 only appear 5.5.0 and after, I would need to set the charset to utf8 as a fallback plan.

Comment: Refere this link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788297/get-mysql-server-version-with-pdo.

Comment: @Nitin thanks for the reference, I searched it google before asking this question...I guess my searched keywords are too ambiguous...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use PDO and query it:

```
SELECT VERSION()
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if the following would work but you might try playing about with:

```
$dsn='mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=db1';
$db = new PDO( $dsn, 'username', 'password' );

if( floatval( $db->getAttribute( PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION ) ) < 5.5 ) {
    /* set alternative charset */
    $db->exec("set names utf8");
}
```

Comment: both method are right, he answered first  :( sorry. I twisted your code a bit to suit my need :) `$charset = $db->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION) >= "5.5.0" ? "utf8mb4" : "utf8";`

Comment: I think the advantage of this method is that you dont need to issue another query or prepare statment to get the version number and then go back and change it dynamically, which is better.